# AngularJS input checkbox model?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have this HTML:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EmailToUser" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EmailToOwner" />
</div>
```

And this in my controller.js:

```
$scope.EmailToUser = true;
$scope.EmailToOwner = false;

$scope.Save = function() {
    if($scope.EmailToUser) {
        alert("I'm supposed to email the user.");
    }

    if($scope.EmailToOwner) {
        alert("I'm supposed to email the owner.");
    }
}
```

This doesn't work, when I click the checkbox the values true/false are constant for some reason. `EmailToUser` is always true and `EmailToOwner` is always false regardless of the checkbox state.

But, if I change the code to this:

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EmailToUser.Value" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EmailToOwner.Value" />
</div>
```

And controller.js:

```
$scope.EmailToUser = {};
$scope.EmailToUser.Value = true;
$scope.EmailToOwner = {};
$scope.EmailToOwner.Value = false;

$scope.Save = function() {
    if($scope.EmailToUser.Value == true) {
        alert("I'm supposed to email the user.");
    }

    if($scope.EmailToOwner.Value == true) {
        alert("I'm supposed to email the owner.");
    }
}
```

It works. Why? I can't seem to figure the differences between #1 and #2.
Am I not creating new objects the same way inside the scope and assigning a true/false value in both ways?

Comment: Is this inside an ng-repeat, ng-switch etc.. or something? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZhfUv0spHCY&feature=youtu.be&t=30m

Comment: can you setup a plunker showing the problem...

Comment: @PSL I believe not, it's a modal, so the code is closed inside the window (I think so). If not, there's no repeat or switch, but there might have a layer or two above it... (I'm using $scope though)

Comment: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes

Answer (score 0):

**controller.js(code)**

```
$scope.EmailToUser = true;
$scope.EmailToOwner = false;
$scope.save1 = function(EmailToUser,EmailToOwner){

    if($scope.EmailToUser) {
        alert("I'm supposed to email the user.");
    }if($scope.EmailToOwner) {
        alert("I'm supposed to email the owner.");
    }
};
```

**controller.html**

```
<div>
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EmailToUser" />
    <input type="checkbox" ng-model="EmailToOwner" />
</div>
<button  type="button" ng-click="save1(EmailToUser,EmailToOwner)">click</button>
```

This code works for me.There is some scope issue.